# Specific input pattern

Tags: input

So I'm asked to write a code in C++ that gets an input with one of the following formats:

bf "pattern" filename

mp "pattern" filename

exit

it goes through a file (filename), looks for a substring of file (pattern), and prints the lines it's used. I'm new to C++ and can't figure out how to specify an input pattern as mentioned above.

bf indicates using Brute-Force function and mp stands for Morris-Pratt.

Thanks

Comment: So where's your codes?

Comment: I haven't gone too far yet. Here's what I have:

 string input = "";

 cout << "Please enter a valid input:\n>";
 getline(cin, input);

    if (input == "exit"){

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; }

    else if (input[0] == "b"){ cout<< "BF algorithm!";}

And I do get an error...

Comment: That's a start! please [edit] that into the question and format it so it is readable and others can see what you are trying to do.